# Rails + Heroku : We're sorry, but something went wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi this is my first time trying to push a project up to Heroku and I am getting the error: `We're sorry, but something went wrong.` I'm not sure how to read the heroku log. Is it the deprecation warnings? I don't have anything in my vendor/plugins... Can someone help me figure out what's wrong? Let me know if you need any other files.

```
2012-10-23T20:29:56+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (10.8ms)
2012-10-23T20:29:56+00:00 app[web.1]: WARN: tilt autoloading 'sass' in a non thread-safe way; explicit require 'sass' suggested.
2012-10-23T20:29:56+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <html>
2012-10-23T20:29:56+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <head>
2012-10-23T20:29:56+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:   <title><%= complete_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
2012-10-23T20:29:56+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (/app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css has already been required):
2012-10-23T20:29:56+00:00 app[web.1]:     8: </head>
2012-10-23T20:29:56+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
2012-10-23T20:29:56+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
2012-10-23T20:29:56+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
2012-10-23T20:29:56+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___2170089293047453939_42303620'
2012-10-23T20:29:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-23T20:29:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-23T20:29:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-23T20:29:56+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 664ms
2012-10-23T20:29:56+00:00 heroku[router]: GET pacific-ravine-3563.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=806ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-10-23T20:29:56+00:00 heroku[router]: GET pacific-ravine-3563.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=0
2012-10-23T20:30:32+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-23T20:30:32+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 66.108.172.226 at 2012-10-23 20:30:32 +0000
2012-10-23T20:30:32+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-23T20:30:32+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2012-10-23T20:30:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.4ms)
2012-10-23T20:30:32+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (/app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css has already been required):
2012-10-23T20:30:32+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <html>
2012-10-23T20:30:32+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <head>
2012-10-23T20:30:32+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:   <title><%= complete_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
2012-10-23T20:30:32+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
2012-10-23T20:30:32+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
2012-10-23T20:30:32+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 26ms
2012-10-23T20:30:32+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-23T20:30:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___2170089293047453939_42303620'
2012-10-23T20:30:32+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-23T20:30:32+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-23T20:30:32+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
2012-10-23T20:30:32+00:00 app[web.1]:     8: </head>
2012-10-23T20:30:32+00:00 heroku[router]: GET pacific-ravine-3563.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=47ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-10-23T21:35:53+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2012-10-23T21:35:56+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2012-10-23T21:35:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select'
2012-10-23T21:35:57+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-10-23 21:35:57] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
2012-10-23T21:36:06+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2012-10-23T21:36:06+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2012-10-23T21:36:08+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2012-10-23T21:36:12+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 45563`
2012-10-23T21:36:17+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-10-23T21:36:17+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release note
s for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-10-23T21:36:17+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-10-23T21:36:21+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2012-10-23T21:36:21+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2012-10-23T21:36:21+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2012-10-23T21:36:21+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.8 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:45563
2012-10-23T21:36:21+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2012-10-23T21:36:22+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-10-23 21:36:22] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2012-10-23T21:36:22+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-10-23 21:36:22] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2012-10-23T21:36:22+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-10-23 21:36:22] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=45563
2012-10-23T21:36:23+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-10-23T22:39:55+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2012-10-23T2
2:39:59+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2012-10-23T22:39:59+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-10-23 22:39:59] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
2012-10-23T22:39:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select'
2012-10-23T22:40:08+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2012-10-23T22:40:08+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2012-10-23T22:40:11+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2012-10-23T22:40:11+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2012-10-24T00:05:40+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2012-10-24T00:05:40+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2012-10-24T00:05:42+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 26314`
2012-10-24T00:05:46+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-10-24T00:05:46+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-10-24T00:05:46+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-10-24T00:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2012-10-24T00:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.8 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:26314
2012-10-24T00:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2012-10-24T00:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2012-10-24T00:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2012-10-24T00:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-10-24 00:05:50] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2012-10-24T00:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-10-24 00:05:50] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=26314
2012-10-24T00:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-10-24 00:05:50] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2012-10-24T00:05:51+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-10-24T00:05:52+00:00 heroku[router]: GET pacific-ravine-3563.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=29ms status=301 bytes=0
2012-10-24T00:05:52+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-24T00:05:52+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-24T00:05:52+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 208.185.23.206 at 2012-10-24 00:05:52 +0000
2012-10-24T00:05:52+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2012-10-24T00:05:53+00:00 app[web.1]: WARN: tilt autoloading 'sass' in a non thread-safe way; explicit require 'sass' suggested.
2012-10-24T00:05:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (16.5ms)
2012-10-24T00:05:53+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 725ms
2012-10-24T00:05:53+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-24T00:05:53+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (/app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css has already been required):
2012-10-24T00:05:53+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <html>
2012-10-24T00:05:53+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <head>
2012-10-24T00:05:53+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:   <title><%= complete_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
2012-10-24T00:05:53+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
2012-10-24T00:05:53+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
2012-10-24T00:05:5
3+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
2012-10-24T00:05:53+00:00 app[web.1]:     8: </head>
2012-10-24T00:05:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___2799874165581384053_34182960'
2012-10-24T00:05:53+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-24T00:05:53+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-24T00:05:53+00:00 heroku[router]: GET pacific-ravine-3563.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=1169ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-10-24T00:05:53+00:00 heroku[router]: GET pacific-ravine-3563.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=0
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
gem "bcrypt-ruby"
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'fancybox-rails'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'
gem 's3_direct_upload'
gem 'aws-s3'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'mail'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'debugger'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'jquery-fileupload-rails'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Comment: What's your Gemfile like? Did you specific `gem "sass", :require => 'sass'`?

Comment: @evanc3 hey evan. I uploaded the gemfile for you. I have sass in my assets.

Comment: Does the application work fine locally, without throwing these error messages? Also, check this answer for a similar issue -  http://stackoverflow.com/a/11351105/429758 - and see if your's is the same situation.

Comment: How many stylesheets you have under `assets/stylesheets`?

Comment: @evanc3 I only have a few. and I can't seem to find any duplication of application.css. My complete code is here on github: https://github.com/EdmundMai/pholderbeta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google with `WARN: tilt autoloading 'sass' in a non thread-safe way; explicit require 'sass' suggested.`

I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12859696/1008230 
Looks like the assets need be compile locally.

Here's some reference:

> For faster asset precompiles, you can partially load your application
>   by setting config.assets.initialize_on_precompile to false in
>   config/application.rb, though in that case templates cannot see
>   application objects or methods. **Heroku requires this to be false.**

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets

> While precompiling assets, in Rails 3.1.1 and up, you can prevent
>   initializing your application and connecting to the database by
>   ensuring that the following line is in your config/application.rb:
>   **config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false**

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar#troubleshooting

Haven't try it myself, hope that helps.

Comment: hey thanks it fixed that error, but my app still doesn't work (i'm guessing it's one of the other errors. I'll post you my new stackoverflow question

Answer (score 3):

First, a couple of pointers. The message `We're sorry, but something went wrong` is what Heroku presents to the end user on any error in your application, because you're in production mode. This is different than what happens in development mode on your local machine, on the theory that you don't want to expose debug stack traces to any user of your application who comes along.

The deprecation warning is a red herring; it's about some gems that Heroku injects into every Rails application, to integrate with their log management stuff.

The really pertinent line in your error log is this one:

```
2012-10-23T20:29:56+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (/app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css has already been required):
```

That's an error somewhere in how stylesheets are being handled, maybe in the asset pipeline feature. That's why @evanc3 is asking about how many stylesheets you have. And, I confess, I don't know how to debug this issue - so this is only a partial answer. Hopefully I've gotten you on the right path.

Comment: so does this mean if I try to deploy the app onto a real domain it won't work? or does heroku just give these errors to make sure that your app is 100% before being put in production?

Comment: It won't work, unless there's something about how your "real domain" is configured vs Heroku. You can try to reproduce it on your local machine by running your server production-style like this: `RAILS_ENV=production rails server`.