# Rails + Heroku : ActionView::Template::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm having trouble deploying my rails app to heroku. I just fixed an error [Rails + Heroku : We're sorry, but something went wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041271/rails-heroku-were-sorry-but-something-went-wrong) but I guess there were more. Can anyone help guide me on how to debug it? I am stuck because heroku doesn't tell me what line the error occurs. Sorry for the bother.

Here's all my code if you want to take a look.
https://github.com/EdmundMai/pholderbeta

Let me know if you want me to paste anything.

Heroku Logs:

```
2012-10-29T16:43:41+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 328ms
2012-10-29T16:43:41+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-29T16:43:41+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 4:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
2012-10-29T16:43:41+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
2012-10-29T16:43:41+00:00 app[web.1]:                                         ^
2012-10-29T16:43:41+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2012-10-29T16:43:41+00:00 app[web.1]:               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2012-10-29T16:43:41+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
2012-10-29T16:43:41+00:00 app[web.1]:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
2012-10-29T16:43:41+00:00 app[web.1]:                AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2012-10-29T16:43:41+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
2012-10-29T16:43:41+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2012-10-29T16:43:41+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: 
2012-10-29T16:43:41+00:00 app[web.1]:     2:        <nav class="clearfix">
2012-10-29T16:43:41+00:00 app[web.1]:     3:            <% if !signed_in? %>
2012-10-29T16:43:41+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:                <%= link_to "home", root_url %>
2012-10-29T16:43:41+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:            <% else %>
2012-10-29T16:43:41+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:                <%= link_to "my profile", current_user %>
2012-10-29T16:43:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:26:in `current_user'
2012-10-29T16:43:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:13:in `signed_in?'
2012-10-29T16:43:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb__4262906123720065777_48014220'
2012-10-29T16:43:41+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-29T16:43:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2281927286696150034_48418280'
2012-10-29T16:43:41+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-29T16:43:41+00:00 heroku[router]: GET pacific-ravine-3563.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=1150
2012-10-29T16:46:26+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2012-10-29T16:46:53+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2012-10-29T16:46:53+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2012-10-29T16:46:56+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 30276`
2012-10-29T16:46:57+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2012-10-29T16:46:58+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-10-29 16:46:58] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
2012-10-29T16:46:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select'
2012-10-29T16:47:04+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-10-29T16:47:04+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-10-29T16:47:08+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2012-10-29T16:47:08+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2012-10-29T16:47:08+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2012-10-29T16:47:08+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.8 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:30276
2012-10-29T16:47:08+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2012-10-29T16:47:08+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2012-10-29T16:47:08+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2012-10-29T16:47:09+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-10-29 16:47:09] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2012-10-29T16:47:09+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-10-29 16:47:09] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2012-10-29T16:47:09+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-10-29 16:47:09] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=30276
2012-10-29T16:47:10+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2012-10-29T16:47:10+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-10-29T16:47:46+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 66.108.172.226 at 2012-10-29 16:47:46 +0000
2012-10-29T16:47:46+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-29T16:47:46+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-29T16:47:46+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2012-10-29T16:47:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (12.3ms)
2012-10-29T16:47:46+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
2012-10-29T16:47:46+00:00 app[web.1]:                                         ^
2012-10-29T16:47:46+00:00 app[web.1]:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
2012-10-29T16:47:46+00:00 app[web.1]:               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2012-10-29T16:47:46+00:00 app[web.1]:                AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2012-10-29T16:47:46+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2012-10-29T16:47:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (59.5ms)
2012-10-29T16:47:46+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
2012-10-29T16:47:46+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-29T16:47:46+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 144ms
2012-10-29T16:47:46+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 4:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
2012-10-29T16:47:46+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
2012-10-29T16:47:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: 
2012-10-29T16:47:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     2:        <nav class="clearfix">
2012-10-29T16:47:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     3:            <% if !signed_in? %>
2012-10-29T16:47:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:                <%= link_to "home", root_url %>
2012-10-29T16:47:46+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2012-10-29T16:47:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:                <%= link_to "my profile", current_user %>
2012-10-29T16:47:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:            <% else %>
2012-10-29T16:47:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:26:in `current_user'
2012-10-29T16:47:46+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-29T16:47:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:13:in `signed_in?'
2012-10-29T16:47:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb__1629561108313014440_42800200'
2012-10-29T16:47:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2023541485350786357_43765980'
2012-10-29T16:47:46+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-29T16:47:46+00:00 heroku[router]: GET pacific-ravine-3563.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=1ms service=12ms status=200 bytes=1150
2012-10-29T17:04:22+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2012-10-29T17:04:41+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2012-10-29T17:04:41+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2012-10-29T17:04:43+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 38347`
2012-10-29T17:04:44+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2012-10-29T17:04:44+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-10-29 17:04:44] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
2012-10-29T17:04:44+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select'
2012-10-29T17:04:50+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-10-29T17:04:50+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-10-29T17:04:50+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2012-10-29T17:04:51+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select'
2012-10-29T17:04:51+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-10-29 17:04:51] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
2012-10-29T17:04:55+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2012-10-29T17:04:55+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.8 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:38347
2012-10-29T17:04:55+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2012-10-29T17:04:55+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2012-10-29T17:04:55+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2012-10-29T17:04:55+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2012-10-29T17:04:55+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2012-10-29T17:04:55+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-10-29 17:04:55] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2012-10-29T17:04:55+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-10-29 17:04:55] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2012-10-29T17:04:55+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-10-29 17:04:55] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=38347
2012-10-29T17:04:56+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-10-29T17:04:57+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20121024185036) do

create_table "albums", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
  t.string   "description"
  t.string   "status"
end

create_table "friendships", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "friend_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  t.string   "status"
end

create_table "ownerships", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
  t.integer "album_id"
  t.integer "user_id"
  t.string  "status"
end

create_table "photos", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "avatar_file_name"
  t.string   "avatar_content_type"
  t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
  t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
  t.datetime "created_at",          :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",          :null => false
  t.integer  "album_id"
end

create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "email"
  t.datetime "created_at",              :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",              :null => false
  t.string   "password_digest"
  t.string   "remember_token"
  t.string   "profilepic_file_name"
  t.string   "profilepic_content_type"
  t.integer  "profilepic_file_size"
  t.datetime "profilepic_updated_at"
  t.string   "password_reset_token"
end

add_index "users", ["remember_token"], :name => "index_users_on_remember_token"
```

end

heroku and local db:version

```
Edmunds-MacBook-Pro:pholder edmundmai$ heroku run rake db:version
Running `rake db:version` attached to terminal... up, run.1
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
Current version: 20120929230317
Edmunds-MacBook-Pro:pholder edmundmai$ rake db:version
Current version: 20121024185036
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the traceback, the error is at line 3 in your template - if you look at the postgres error, the message you're getting is `ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist`. Have you run your database migrations?

Comment: looks like I did (I did a rake db:migrate after reading your comment and nothing changed... I'll paste my schema for you

Comment: What about `heroku run rake db:migrate`? What does `heroku run rake db:version` tell you, compared to `rake db:version` locally?

Comment: I've pasted my heroku db version and local db version above. after running `heroku run rake db:migrate` should I do any git push heroku master or git add or git commit?

Comment: The versions in your updated question are very clearly different -- Heroku is `20120929230317`, while your box is `20121024185036` -- so you definitely need to run migrations. Did you forget to check them in?

Comment: o...but I just ran `heroku run rake db:migrate` before `heroku run rake db:version` so how could that be? How would I "check them in"?

Comment: I think I might know what the problem is... I had a few errors on my migrations that worked when I ran them with my local rails, but caused the migrations to stop abruptly midway. I'll let you know in a few minutes if that's the issue

Comment: yep that was the solution. It was because my migration files had errors in them. Although they ran successfully locally, heroku requires them to be error free